# How to bind from DataTemplate to the GridViewColumns item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, datatemplate

I have a `ListView` with `DataTemplate` defined in `Resources`. I would like to forward the content of the `GridViewColumn` to the `DataTemplate` so that the `DataTemplate` can be reused for multiple `GridViewColumns`. I have a property called `Property1` which I want to bind to the `GridViewColumn` and then forwarded it to the `DataTemplate` where it will be displayed in the `TextBlock`. However, `GridViewColumn` doesn't have any `Content` property I could bind it to.

Here is a stripped down code:

```
<ListView>

  <ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PropertyTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text"{Binding}" />
    <DataTemplate>
  </ListView.Resources>

  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <!-- No Content property in GridViewColumn -->
      <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyTemplate}" Content={Binding Property1} />
    <GridView>
  </ListView.View>

</ListView>
```

How can I forward the the bound property from the GridViewColumn to the GridViewColumn's DataTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

This should work:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PropertyTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyTemplate}"  />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**Previous answer (doesn't work):**
Use DisplayMemberBinding property. You also probably want to set the header text for your column:

```
<GridView>
      <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyTemplate}" DisplayMemberBinding={Binding Property1} Header="Some column"/>
</GridView>
```

You will also need to set ItemsSource on your ListView.

Comment: That doesn't work because setting DisplayMemberBinding overrides the DataTemplate.

Comment: Ah, ok. Have you tried specifying the property name in your DataTemplate: <TextBlock Text"{Binding Property1}" />

Comment: You need to specify the ItemsSource on your ListView first of course.

Comment: Yes I have specified the ItemsSource. Also doing <TextBlock Text"{Binding Property1}" /> works BUT the DataTemplate doesn't know which property it will be linked to and that is why I need to bind it in the GridViewColumn and then forward it.

Comment: I just tried it and it works ok. DataTemplate doesn't need to know what you're binding to, the binding will be resolved at runtime. Are you getting an error?

Comment: No but the `GridViewColumn` shows the default `DataTemplate` for string (which happens to be also a `TextBlock`) instead of my custom DataTemplate.

Comment: I tried changing the datatemplate to something other than just TextBlock and it works ok. Are you sure you doing exactly what I suggested in my UPDATED answer above? Try changing your template to this and see if it is displayed correctly:          <DataTemplate x:Key="PropertyTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>Name</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

Comment: Your updated answer works but defeats the purpose of abstracting out the `DataTemplate`. As I mentioned before, the `DataTemplate` has to be reused on many `GridViewColumns` and therefore the Property1 has to be bound to the `GridViewColumn` and not inside the `DataTemplate`.